# Flutter svg is not loading

Tags: flutter, svg

I am currently trying to add svg from my asset/icons folder but when ever i run it throws this at me. Please any idea what is wrong here??

```
/// An [AssetBundle] that loads resources using platform messages.
class PlatformAssetBundle extends CachingAssetBundle {
@override
Future<ByteData> load(String key) async {
final Uint8List encoded = utf8.encoder.convert(Uri(path: Uri.encodeFull(key)).path);
final ByteData? asset =
    await ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger.send('flutter/assets', encoded.buffer.asByteData());
if (asset == null)
  throw FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');
return asset;
}
}
```

Also this is the code i'm using

```
class categories extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<Map<String, dynamic>> categories = [
  {"icon": "/assets/icons/water.svg", "text": "Water"},
  {"icon": "/assets/icons/food.svg", "text": "Food"},
  {"icon": "/assets/icons/education.svg", "text": "Education"},
  {"icon": "/assets/icons/poverty.svg", "text": "No Poverty"},
  {"icon": "/assets/icons/health.svg", "text": "Good Health"},
];
return SizedBox(
    width: getProportionateScreenWidth(55),
    child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: SvgPicture.asset(categories[0]["icon"]),
      ),
    ));
}
}
```

This is what my pubspec.yaml looks like

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

flutter_svg: ^1.0.3 # help us to use SVG in our app
provider: ^6.0.0 # for State management

flutter:
uses-material-design: true
assets:
 - assets/images/
 - assets/icons/
```

Comment: Ohh got it !  remove `/` from path just  assets/icons/water.svg enough

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh thanks a bunch I've been stuck here since last night. I tested it and its works fine. I almost started clapping aloud on the train :)

Comment: that / was the problem

Comment: if it help you up the comment thanks